# Can I see how many pixels wide and long my image is in Google Drawings?

Tags: google-drawings

Is there a way to see how many pixels wide and long my image is in Google Drawings?

Answer (score 1):

actualy there is a way:

1. select **File**
2. select **Page setup...**
3. select **Custom**
4. select **Pixels**

[image]
[image]